# How to integrate oracle DBMS in datagrip IDE

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

I have already installed oracle database 10g express edition so can I use this oracle DBMS as data driver in datagrip IDE?
I tried to copy the oracle.exe's path in the "select database driver files" window but it doesn't show the .exe file

Comment: First, oracle 10g has been out of support -- and not even publicly available -- for a few years now.  Second, I've never known any front-end tool to require any direct knowledge of oracle.exe.  I think you are mis-interpreting what datagrip needs for proper configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the datagrip docs at https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/help/getting-started-with-datagrip.html.  The give an example for MySQL but from that I can see what you should supply for Oracle:

In the Data Sources and Drivers page, under the "general" tab, you should supply:

HOST: - the host name or ip address of the computer that is running the oracle database.  This should match the HOST that you see when you run 'lsnrctl status' -- the same host name that the listener is listening for.  If it is 'localhost', it will only work if both the client (datagrip) and the database are on the same machine.
PORT:  by default this should be 1521

Database:  Since you installed Express Edition, this will be "XE".  Any other edition and it gets a bit more complex.

User and password:  whatever is appropriate for the credentials you created on your database.  You probably should have created a database user just for use by datagrip.  You should NOT use SYS or SYSTEM.

URL.  (overrides settings above)  So don't supply it and don't override the previous settings.  The database itself is not running "on a url" -- that would be an additional, optional, intermediary.

Comment: so the driver must be downloaded?

Comment: What driver are you asking about?  What values DID you supply in the fields to set up your connection definition? To access an Oracle database, you have to have oracle client software, or perhaps a jdbc-thin driver.  To be honest, I"ve been working with oracle over 20 years and never heard of datagrip before now.  You might find more help on their own forum at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us   I just popped over there and see several threads on this subject...

Comment: Why didn't you use just the "Download drivers" button inside DataGrip?

Comment: @moscas proxy server does not like downloading .jar files or .exe files. they're executables.

Comment: I see. You still have problems with connecting to Oracle? If yes, I can help you.